# getting error while querying in firebase firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: n]I am getting an error saying that the query requires an index I have created a composite index in firestore still not working any idea plz help

This is the error i am getting after running the query

```
Error: FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here:
https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/jssr-6e16c/firestore/indexes?create_compo
site=Ckhwcm9qZWN0cy9qc3NyLTZlMTZjL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9BZG1pb
i9pbmRleGVzL18QARoLCgdwaG9uZU5vEAEaDQoJcGFydHlOYW1lEAIaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAg
(failed-precondition)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:58377/dart_sdk.js:4776:11)
    at handleThenable
    (http://localhost:58377/packages/firebase/src/storage.dart.lib.js:3237:21)
    at handleThenable.throw (<anonymous>)
    at onError (http://localhost:58377/dart_sdk.js:35663:38)
    at _RootZone.runBinary (http://localhost:58377/dart_sdk.js:35547:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleError (http://localhost:58377/dart_sdk.js:30969:50)
    at handleError (http://localhost:58377/dart_sdk.js:31482:51)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:58377/dart_sdk.js:31505:17)
    at _Future.new.[_completeError] (http://localhost:58377/dart_sdk.js:31366:23)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback
    (http://localhost:58377/dart_sdk.js:31401:31)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:58377/dart_sdk.js:35759:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:58377/dart_sdk.js:35765:13)
    at http://localhost:58377/dart_sdk.js:31707:9Application finished.
```

And the query generating error is below.
In this phoneNo and lrNo both are fields in document , but they are String but only contains numerical values(validated in clients side using regex).

```
    var temp = await fireStore
        .collection("Admin")
        .where("phoneNo", isEqualTo: TextFieldData.phoneNo)
        .orderBy("lrNo", descending: false)
        .getDocuments()
        .then((value) => value);

    return temp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying using more than one field, then you need to create an index. In your code, you are filtering using `phoneNo` and ordering using `lrNo`, therefore you can create an index using the url in the error.

> Error: FirebaseError: The query requires an index. You can create it here:
>   https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/jssr-6e16c/firestore/indexes?create_compo
>   site=Ckhwcm9qZWN0cy9qc3NyLTZlMTZjL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9BZG1pb
>   i9pbmRleGVzL18QARoLCgdwaG9uZU5vEAEaDQoJcGFydHlOYW1lEAIaDAoIX19uYW1lX18QAg

just click the url, it will navigate to the page and create an index.

Comment: after doing this i am not getting any data using the same query

Comment: i have added an image plz check my data layout.In the above image document-id  and lrNo both are same.

Comment: Has nothing to do with that, read the answer again.. In the query u are using two fields, all u have to do is click the link and create an index very simple

Comment: When u use a single field in the query firestore creates an index for u automatically. Indexes are used for performance to retrieve data faster, but they don't automatically create indexes for compound queries

Comment: I have done that already after doing that I am not getting any data earlier I am getting data (without order by query). but in an unordered fashion.

Comment: u have a typo change `lrNo` into `lrN0` zero instead of "o"